# Problem with Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

**Projects do not run, on screen emulator only "ANDROID"**

WinXP pro SP3/Eclipse Galileo

java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

**My actions:**

1.Start the emulator(Platform:2.1 API Level:7), wait until the window DDMS status will change to ONLINE

2.Launches helloandroid from examples -> Run as Android Application

Console:

```
Android Launch!
[2010-05-03 21:44:34 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2010-05-03 21:44:34 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2010-05-03 21:44:34 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'my_vm'
[2010-05-03 21:44:34 - HelloAndroid] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2010-05-03 21:44:34 - HelloAndroid] Device API version is 7 (Android 2.1)
[2010-05-03 21:44:34 - HelloAndroid] Uploading HelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-05-03 21:44:35 - HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk...
[2010-05-03 21:45:07 - HelloAndroid] Success!
[2010-05-03 21:45:08 - HelloAndroid] Starting activity com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid on device 
[2010-05-03 21:45:28 - HelloAndroid] ActivityManager: DDM dispatch reg wait timeout
[2010-05-03 21:45:28 - HelloAndroid] ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk 52454151: no handler defined
[2010-05-03 21:45:28 - HelloAndroid] ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk 48454c4f: no handler defined
[2010-05-03 21:45:28 - HelloAndroid] ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined
[2010-05-03 21:45:28 - HelloAndroid] ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined
[2010-05-03 21:45:52 - HelloAndroid] Device not ready. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2010-05-03 21:45:52 - HelloAndroid] ActivityManager: android.util.AndroidException: Can't connect to activity manager; is the system running?
[2010-05-03 21:45:55 - HelloAndroid] Starting activity com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid on device 
[2010-05-03 21:46:11 - HelloAndroid] ActivityManager: DDM dispatch reg wait timeout
......
```

DDMS console (only errors and warnings)

```
05-03 17:43:52.437: ERROR/vold(26): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
05-03 17:43:52.437: ERROR/vold(26): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
05-03 17:43:52.437: ERROR/vold(26): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
05-03 17:43:52.437: ERROR/vold(26): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
05-03 17:48:34.036: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080093 (res/drawable-mdpi/sym_def_app_icon.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:34.406: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080002 (res/drawable-mdpi/arrow_down_float.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:35.836: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800b4 (res/drawable/btn_check.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:36.076: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800b7 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_label_background.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:36.106: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800b8 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:36.147: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800bd (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:36.437: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080004 (res/drawable/btn_default.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:36.716: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080005 (res/drawable/btn_default_small.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:36.966: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080006 (res/drawable/btn_dropdown.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:37.326: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080008 (res/drawable/btn_plus.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:37.707: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080007 (res/drawable/btn_minus.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:38.057: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080009 (res/drawable/btn_radio.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:38.776: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108000a (res/drawable/btn_star.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:39.327: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080125 (res/drawable/btn_toggle.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:39.416: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080187 (res/drawable-mdpi/ic_emergency.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:39.506: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080012 (res/drawable-mdpi/divider_horizontal_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:39.576: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080014 (res/drawable-mdpi/divider_horizontal_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:40.126: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080016 (res/drawable/edit_text.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:40.507: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080161 (res/drawable/expander_group.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:41.036: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080062 (res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:41.177: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080217 (res/drawable-mdpi/menu_background.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:41.256: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080218 (res/drawable-mdpi/menu_background_fill_parent_width.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:41.567: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080219 (res/drawable/menu_selector.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:41.706: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080224 (res/drawable-mdpi/panel_background.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:41.849: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108022e (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_bottom_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:42.026: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108022f (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_bottom_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:42.156: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080230 (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_bottom_medium.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:42.276: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080231 (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_center_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:42.376: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080232 (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_center_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:42.507: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080235 (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_full_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:42.606: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080238 (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_top_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:42.696: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080239 (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_top_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:42.946: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108006d (res/drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:43.076: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108023f (res/drawable/progress_small.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:43.456: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080240 (res/drawable/progress_small_titlebar.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:43.957: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080262 (res/drawable-mdpi/scrollbar_handle_horizontal.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:44.036: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080263 (res/drawable-mdpi/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:44.176: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080071 (res/drawable/spinner_dropdown_background.xml) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:44.317: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080326 (res/drawable-mdpi/title_bar_shadow.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:44.496: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801c6 (res/drawable-mdpi/indicator_code_lock_drag_direction_green_up.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:44.607: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801c7 (res/drawable-mdpi/indicator_code_lock_drag_direction_red_up.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:45.956: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801c8 (res/drawable-mdpi/indicator_code_lock_point_area_default.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:46.407: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801c9 (res/drawable-mdpi/indicator_code_lock_point_area_green.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:46.696: WARN/Zygote(29): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801ca (res/drawable-mdpi/indicator_code_lock_point_area_red.png) that varies with configuration!!
05-03 17:48:56.307: ERROR/BatteryService(170): usbOnlinePath not found
05-03 17:48:56.336: ERROR/BatteryService(170): batteryVoltagePath not found
05-03 17:48:56.350: ERROR/BatteryService(170): batteryTemperaturePath not found
05-03 17:48:56.696: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(170): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
05-03 17:48:57.847: WARN/SurfaceFlinger(170): ro.sf.lcd_density not defined, using 160 dpi by default.
05-03 17:49:02.116: WARN/UsageStats(170): Usage stats version changed; dropping
05-03 17:49:05.036: WARN/zipro(182): Unable to open zip '/data/local/bootanimation.zip': No such file or directory
05-03 17:49:06.297: WARN/zipro(182): Unable to open zip '/system/media/bootanimation.zip': No such file or directory
05-03 17:49:50.637: WARN/PackageManager(170): Running ENG build: no pre-dexopt!
05-03 17:53:59.196: WARN/PackageManager(170): Unknown permission com.google.android.providers.gmail.permission.WRITE_GMAIL in package com.android.settings
05-03 17:53:59.238: WARN/PackageManager(170): Unknown permission com.google.android.providers.gmail.permission.READ_GMAIL in package com.android.settings
05-03 17:53:59.286: WARN/PackageManager(170): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.settings
05-03 17:53:59.517: WARN/PackageManager(170): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.providers.contacts
05-03 17:53:59.656: WARN/PackageManager(170): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.cp in package com.android.providers.contacts
05-03 17:53:59.717: WARN/PackageManager(170): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.mail in package com.android.contacts
05-03 17:53:59.796: WARN/PackageManager(170): Unknown permission android.permission.ADD_SYSTEM_SERVICE in package com.android.phone
05-03 17:54:00.126: WARN/PackageManager(170): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.development
05-03 17:54:00.206: WARN/PackageManager(170): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.ALL_SERVICES in package com.android.development
05-03 17:54:00.206: WARN/PackageManager(170): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.YouTubeUser in package com.android.development
05-03 17:54:00.237: WARN/PackageManager(170): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.ACCESS_GOOGLE_PASSWORD in package com.android.development
05-03 17:54:00.258: WARN/PackageManager(170): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.browser
05-03 17:54:25.456: WARN/ResourceType(170): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f0700e5
05-03 17:54:25.486: WARN/ResourceType(170): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020031
05-03 17:54:25.536: WARN/ResourceType(170): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020030
05-03 17:54:25.576: WARN/ResourceType(170): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f050000
05-03 17:54:38.708: WARN/SharedBufferStack(182): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out (identity=0, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
```

Comment: Off the cuff, it feels like your computer is too slow. What are the specifications of the computer?

Answer (score 2):

If you're running this example from the apidemos package, don't. Find an example project of "hello world" that's not packaged with a ton of other apps, and run it on its own.

For instance, this one looks fine I think:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Your android manifest xml file is asking for all kinds of permissions it doesn't even need, that's why I'm guessing that this example is packaged with many-many other examples. And on a side-note, be sure to close the projects that you're not using (on windows, right-click and do close project, this will allow your Eclipse workspace to load faster).

Answer (score 0):

*(Sorry, couldn't add this as a comment, anyway this is not answer...)*
I think you will need at least 2 GB RAM to test on the emulator - without debugging; 4 GB is good if you want to debug, stop on breakpoints, see current values, threads and the rest.

Otherwise please test directly on physical Android devices... please make sure you have the proper USB driver/s from Google (you can get that from SDK manager).

Regards